# Handling large result set in unixODBC

Tags: odbc, resultset, unixodbc

Am using unixODBC(in my CentOS 6.0 machine) to connect to remote database(Postgres/Sybase), and I have a really large result set in my remote database. Is there any way I can limit the number of results pulled back when calling SQLExecute()? For example, if there are around 6 million records in the remote database, I would like to run my select query to return only a limited number of results on SQLExecute (e.g 1000 records). Once I have read those 1000 records with SQLFetch, then the next SQLFetch should get the next batch of results from the remote database.

I have read manuals of UnixODBC and could not find solution. Any help/link is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vaishnavi

Comment: If you are doing this with a program that uses the ODBC API you can just stop calling SQLFetch when you have the required number of rows. If you are doing it from an application, either the application might have a setting for this, or the database might let you limit results (possibly with some SQL you can run as a pre-query step from the application - lots of third party applications support that).

Comment: @mc110 , Am using ODBC API, my problem is that while calling SQLExecute() itself, my pc's memory is occupied by the size of entire records of remote table. I would like to restrict the number of records to transfer from remote database during SQLExecute() itself. IS there any configuration settings available in ODBC for that? For eg,while using cursor with "select * from remote_table", I like to initially fetch only 1000 records max and once after I read those records using SQLFetch,then next set of 1000 records should be transferred from remote database.In this way,I can avoid memory wastage.

Comment: That sounds like something specific to your ODBC driver. With the ODBC driver for the product I'm most familiar with, no rows will come back to the client until the first SQLFetch call is made, but it sounds like in your case the driver pulls back a lot / all rows on the SQLExecute call. You could check documentation for that driver to see if it has any extensions to the basic API to let you restrict how many rows are pulled back on SQLExecute.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Too many records to fetch, and the statement would consequentially error.

For me, the solution involved appending ';UseDeclareFetch=1' at the end of my connection string (I notice you're using Postgres).

For more detailed information on the use of this (consequences, etc), follow this link:

https://www.simba.com/products/PostgreSQL/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/linux/content/odbc/re/options/ui/declarefetchmode.htm